# How to get 2 same named .Net Dlls to work together?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dll

I have a certain DLL in my application which works fine by itself. However, the vendor released a newer version of the dll that I am attempting to incorporate using Visual Studio. The DLLs share the same filename, while using different namespaces, and the later one is not backwards compatible.

To get VS to even use the newer one I renamed the file which makes sense. However, every time I build the application it only wants to copy the newer dll to the application folder and basically ignores the older dll. I have tried 'copy local' and other settings with no luck. I could probably add the dll to the GAC and be done with it, but don't really want to.

How can I get VS to treat both as totally separate items?

Comment: Probably not backwards compatible for a reason, unless the vendor is simply sloppy.

Comment: When you say "work with visual studio" is it a visual studio plugin?  I don't understand what visual studio has to do with it if it's not.

Comment: Visual studio is the IDE so it is what is doing the building and such. It is not a plugin, but my IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved the problem with a simple post build step to copy the dll to the application folder. VS treated each different, but at build time only copied the later.

Answer (score 4):

> I have a certain DLL in my application which works fine by itself. However, the vendor released a newer version of the dll that I am attempting to incorporate using Visual Studio

Why don't you just remove the old DLL completely and change your code to make the new one work?  Why would you want to use both at the same time?

Comment: Much easier said than done. I have working code for the old one and working code for the new one. Why can they not coexist?

Comment: Why would you want them to?  You use the new one or the old one.  Of course a new version may break your code, forcing you to make some changes.  That is a choice you make, but don't use both.

Comment: Why would I not want them to? The DLLs do similar things, but on totally different data. My clients have the old data and are using that, while my new clients will have the option of the old and new data. Saying 'just use the new' is quite ignorant of the underlying problem. It sounds like a helpdesk person always saying things like just format the hardrive.

Comment: Which is better telling the old clients they can not use the new software or a post build step? I would hate to see the applications you design if you answered with the former.

Comment: I think you are so locked in to what you think is the only course of action that you haven't stopped to consider making the new DLL work for all of your customers.

Comment: Honestly, you seem very arrogant, pig-headed, and close-minded to any other suggestions.  You are not someone I would ever want to work with.

Answer (score 2):

You can deploy the two DLLs to different subdirectories. You'll then need to set up rules in your app.config that tell .NET where to find each version.

An example based on the [MSDN page for the `<codeBase>` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efs781xb.aspx):

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="myAssembly"
                              publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"
                              culture="neutral" />
            <codeBase version="1.0.0.0"
                      href="Version1/myAssembly.dll"/>
            <codeBase version="2.0.0.0"
                      href="Version2/myAssembly.dll"/>
         </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

At build time you'll need to set Copy Local=false, to prevent Visual Studio from becoming confused. You'll also need a post-build step that sets up the Version1 and Version2 subdirectories.

Note that this assumes you can tell the DLLs apart based on the version number.

Comment: The post build statement made me remember I could do those things. It has been a while since I needed to. Thanks.